# Python Datetime strptime ValueError: does not match format

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

having a little trouble pulling the date from a file of mine.

Date strings are in the format: `"06/08/2016` # Note the parenthesis

and my strptime command is: `date = datetime.datetime.strptime(text[0], '\"%m/%d/%Y').date()`

but I get the following as an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "budget.py", line 20, in <module>
    print datetime.datetime.strptime(text[0], "\"%m/%d/%Y")
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
   ValueError: time data '"Date' does not match format '"%m/%d/%Y'
```

Not sure whats wrong. Don't think its anything simple, as most ValueErrors with datetime are caused with a mismatch year qualifier (%y and %Y). Anyone have any ideas? Thanks and kudos in advance! :)

---

As the answers below I was getting the error by not removing the '\"' in the format. I was expecting that I would have needed to included the " mark of the string, but apparently datetime didn't mind! Thanks all!

Comment: I think the backslash is messing up the function. Try `datetime.datetime.strptime(text[0], "%m/%d/%Y").date()`, and it should work!

I'm also not sure what you mean by "Note the parenthesis"

Comment: Yeah that's it! The string had a parenthesis in it, so I was expecting that it would need to have been escaped, but apparently not!

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells me that your string data is literally

```
"Date
```

and not

```
"06/08/2016
```

as claimed. Otherwise, your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

This way?

```
text  = '"06/08/2016'
format = '"%m/%d/%Y'
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(text, format).date()
```

Comment: Not enough reputation to comment @wim answer, hope you'll read it. Seems to me that the main problem is as you say, passing a literal '"Date' instead of a proper date string. But I think that other problem may be passing the date as text[0]. Wouldn't that pass just the first character?